# celebrities known for Martial arts

Tags: mixed-martial-arts

who are some celebrities known for Martial arts. We know only about **jackie chan and bruce lee**. Is there any other **celebrities** who are good at martial arts ?

Comment: This is asking for list of things which StackExchange does not do well at all. Please read [the help on what not to ask](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: "Celebrity" may be too broad. Of course there are some actors and even musicians known for it (eg. Jackie Chan, or Andy Lau), but eg. Mayweather, Klytsjko, Badr Hari, Hulk Hogan, etc. are all celebrities too. Do you want a list of all known boxers, UFC fighters, K1 fighters, etc?

Comment: @Raf The problem here is not the definition of celebrity. It is the asking for a list of things which cannot be answered definitively as per the [FAQ](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This is why poll or list questions are always off topic on stack exchange sites. [What is the definition of a list question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124450/227017) Those questions are much better suited to a forum.

Comment: This question would be better if you narrowed it down - style, level of achievement... something.  Do you mean celebrities that the US knows? Because there's plenty of celebrity martial artists from the 90s HK movie scene.  How much martial arts training? Like, before or outside of acting/singing/whatever? Many stars end up doing training for specific roles, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Willie Nelson was awarded his 5th degree black belt on his 81st birthday. Unlike many celebrities holding black belts, Willie has been training for 20 years to earn that rank (i.e. it's real, not honorary).

Chuck Norris is an accomplished Tang Soo Do practitioner and instructor.

Steven Segal is an aikido practitioner. He is unique in that (for a while anyways) he was the only westerner to open a successful martial arts school in Tokyo.

Jet Li is a kung fu practitioner.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, Chuck Norris was a celeb *because* of his martial arts ([his original art is Karate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Norris#Martial_arts_career)), he was a multiple world champ (FWIW) and he had celebrity clients when he taught - all before he got into movies and TV.

Answer (score -1):

I'll share some BJJ ones that I know of:

- Ashton Kutcher is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Purple Belt
- Keanu Reeves is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Purple Belt
- Chuck Norris is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Black Belt
- Joe Rogan is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Black Belt
- Anthony Bourdain is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Blue Belt
- Paul Walker is/was a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Brown Belt (awarded Black Belt at funeral)
- Joey Diaz is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Blue Belt
- Scott Eastwood is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Blue Belt
- Steve Irwin is/was a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Blue Belt
- Guy Ritchie is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Black Belt

Comment: Thanks for the answer...... sorry that as i already accepted other answer, i dont want to unaccept it......

Comment: … And this, right here, is why list questions are frowned upon on stack…